# Angularjs: How to send data from one view to another view

Tags: angularjs, redirect, user-interface, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am sending the data from one view to another view in AngularJS.

In one page I am searching the data using particular user id, and it displays multiple results in response. Then by clicking the below URL:

```
<a href="/whole_result">User id</a>
```

i.e User id, it will displays whole data in another page (I am already storing the object in the `$scope.userData`). But the object `$scope.userData` does not display any data in that object.

Example

```
$scope.userData.name --> no value
$scope.userData.year --> no value
```

Before that I am redirecting to the next page using `$location.path("/next_path");`

Answer (score 3):

You can specify parameters when you are nagivating to the new view `newRoute/23`

and when you define your route you need to specify the parameter using a colon:

```
.when('/newRoute/:myParam', {controller: 'NewRouteCtrl'...
```

and then grab that value in the new route's controller by injecting `$routeParams`

```
.controller('NewRouteCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams){
    //get the param value:
    $scope.scopeVar = $routeParams.myParam;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either share data between views/states/routes/etc by using a parent scope to both controllers or via a service.   If both controllers share a common parent, they can both get access to your shared data.  With a service, since they are singletons, you can store an object in a service and of course inject it into any controller.

Comment: parent scope means $rootScope, it think it is global object ?. I don't have much idea about it........ Thanks for your Answer.

Comment: $rootScope is the ancestor of all scopes.  You can define parent scopes that aren't rootScope too.  Might help for you to read the angular docs.

Answer (score 0):

Store your data in a service.

```
app.service('SessionUser', function () {
  this.name = 'bob';
  this.year = 2014;
});

app.controller('CtrlOne', function (SessionUser, $http, $scope) {
  $scope.userData = $http.get('/session/user', function (data) {
    SessionUser.year = data.year;
    SessionUser.name = data.name;
  });
});

app.controller('CtrlTwo', function (SessionUser, $scope) {
  $scope.user = SessionUser;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Below are the option

1. For small kind of data you can use $cookieStore
2. For large kind of data , you can use localstorage, set data into localstorage and then you retrieve the data on another page.